# Value return when no rows in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, return

I have a PDO function:

```
function(){
    $success=$this->query($query, $bindvalues);

    return ($success == true) ? $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) : false;
}
```

When I perform a select query that returns a row (or more), it will return for example:

```
array(1) { ["Id"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

When the query fails (if I have a wrong syntax for example), it will return FALSE.

But if no rows are found with the query it also returns FALSE.

So the return value with an error in the query and with no rows will both return FALSE. How is that possible? I need to return FALSE only when there is an error in the query, and I need to return NULL for example when there are no results. Is there something wrong in my function?

Thanks!

Comment: It helps to read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-returnvalues

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If no row was found PDO::fetch returns false. This is a fact. So change your function:

```
function(){
    $success = $this->query($query, $bindvalues);
    if(!$success) {
        //handle error
        return false;
    }
    $rows = $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $rows ?: null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is very simple, but I didn't know that PDO return false when no row was found. I think MySQL doesn't?

Comment: mysql will also return false. [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/net/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

Comment: Oke thanks, but when I do not return `$this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` but `$this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` an empty array is returned!

Comment: @Jordy Read the manual for that method! `fetch` fetches and returns *the next row*. There are two possible return values: the next row or *"there is no next row"*. `fetchAll` returns an array of all rows; that feasibly can be an empty array. The two methods do entirely different things.

Comment: You can do `return $rows ?: null;` instead of `return $rows ? $rows : null;`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
function fetchRow($query, $bindvalues)
{
    $stmt = $this->query($query, $bindvalues);
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Comment: He want to return a `null` when there isn't any row, not a `false`.

Comment: @PhoneixS it makes no sense so just dismiss such a whim :)