# What exactly a PDO statement will return when no rows match the query criteria?

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

I'm building a class to login users, so everything works great on localhost, but when i upload the files to the server, the code doesn't work as espected...

I checked this question [Value return when no rows in PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530267/value-return-when-no-rows-in-pdo) but i couldn't make it work...

My goal is to be able to retrieve the data from the Database and then check either the password is correct or not. I need 3 feedbacks:

1. User Doesn't exist
2. Pass/User combination doesn't match.
3. All good, proceed and login the user.

First I call the class:

```
$a = $login->login_user_admin($_POST['user']);
```

Then I get the result: **Updated full class & connection**

```
class Database extends PDO
{
private $dbname = "xxx";
private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "xxx";
private $pass = "xxx";
private $port = 5432;
private $dbh;

public function __construct() 
{
    try {

        $this->dbh = parent::__construct("pgsql:host=$this->host;port=$this->port;dbname=$this->dbname;user=$this->user;password=$this->pass");

    } catch(PDOException $e) {

        echo  $e->getMessage(); 

    }

}

public function close_con() 
{

    $this->dbh = null; 

}

}

class Users
{

private $con;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->con = new Database();
    $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}

public function login_user_admin($user)
{

    try{

        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT name,salt,pass FROM users.users_admin WHERE name=? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute(array($user));

        $this->con->close_con();
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {

        echo  $e->getMessage();

    }   
}
}
```

Finally I process:

```
$data = [];
if ($a!=true) {

$data['success'] = false;
$data['message'] = 'User doesn't exist';

}else{

//All good proceed to chk the password.
}
```

I tried with [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)... didn't work on server either, they all work on local tough. I also try using fetchAll() and checking the empty string but i couldn't make it.

I went to check on the PHP versions on the server and local and they both running on 5.5 so I run out of ideas for now and I will appreciate some help on this.

**Update!**
I upload a file with only this code to check if I am getting any result from the database and I realize I am not,

```
include '../functions/functions.php';
$login = new Users();
$a = $login->login_user_admin("emirocast");
print_r($a);
var_dump($a);
```

The only user in the database right now is "emirocast" so i should get the result but i get a bool(false) instead.

The other thing I noticed is that the server is running Postgresql 8.4 and I am running 9.1 locally. Can this be the problem here?

Comment: Please check the logs and make sure there isn't something wrong on your server.

Comment: show the complete implementation of method `login_user_admin` instead of a snippet of codes.

Comment: With a test script, test if you have a correct connection ( with a statement like "SELECT NOW()" in MySQL)

Comment: It works, i tried Array select now() and i got this; ( [now] => 2015-03-08 12:22:35.632479-04:30 ) array(1) { ["now"]=> string(32) "2015-03-08 12:22:35.632479-04:30" };

Comment: Now I tried with a simple "select * " and i got this on the error logs: [08-Mar-2015 17:02:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[42501]: Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR:  permission denied for schema users
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM users.users_admin
                      ^ in /home/vipplati/public_html/newsite/black_theme/interface/functions/functions.php on line 57
[08-Mar-2015 17:02:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /home/vipplati/public_html/newsite/black_theme/interface/functions/functions.php on line 60 ; I guess is a permission issue then

Comment: ok, is working now, it was a permission issue, i changed the user for the default one and it worked, thanks everyone for helping narrowing the issue