# Ajax message display issue

Tags: php, ajax

I think I've worked out that the issue relates to binding params for PDO instead of including the values in the select statement.

Now googling how to bind array values where there will be a variable number of them per query type. For example there may be one, two or three category (col) values sought.

My primary script submits an ajax request to a secondary script.

Two params are sent and are being received in most scenarios.
eg department:mens-fashion, category:coats-and-jackets

In all but a few scenarios, the ajax query is successful and returns as expected. However, for some pairings of params, nothing is displayed in the page or in console.

Having returned from the query script immediately after building the query, I know the query is always working OK.  (Copying and pasting into phpMyAmdin brings me the correct resultset.)

So it seems the key part of the script is the fetch routine. How can I catch an error message from PDO in the next line?...

```
$filtered_results = $filtered_statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$debugInfo = array('debug' => vsprintf(str_replace("?", "%s", $filtered_statement->queryString), $opts ));
```

[edit]

```
if ( is_array($filtered_results) ) {
$filtered_results = array_merge($debugInfo, $filtered_results);
} else {
$filtered_results = $debugInfo;
}
```

[/edit]
debug info still only being returned if the query was a success.

```
$filtered_results_json = json_encode($filtered_results);

echo( $filtered_results_json );
```

Please would anyone point me to a solution where, the failed query will display in the calling script.  The data required is in the db so I am still really stuck on trying to display failure messages.

Comment: If you don't know where your error comes from, why do you only share the "key part of the script"? You're not even sharing your SQL query or how you handle that ajax call. Hard to help here. But if this is all you can share and assuming your ajax call is properly written, try debugging manually with `echo()` followed by `exit()` in your PHP script at different locations and see if you get the expected result when printing on ajax call success/complete.

Comment: The script is working for most pairs of params submitted to it.  I am trying to get the query that fails, to find out what's going wrong with the submitted params, or something else that's occasionally (though consistently), going awry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether an array is returned or not. If nothing was found no array is being returned - and you can't use array_merge.

```
$filtered_results = $filtered_statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$debugInfo = array('debug' => vsprintf(str_replace("?", "%s", $filtered_statement->queryString), $opts )); 

if ( is_array($filtered_results) ) {
    $filtered_results = array_merge($debugInfo, $filtered_results);
} else {
    $filtered_results = $debugInfo;
}

$filtered_results_json = json_encode($filtered_results);

echo( $filtered_results_json );
```

See this as well: [Value return when no rows in PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530267/value-return-when-no-rows-in-pdo)

Comment: That's a great help. thanks. I now know for sure the query is correct, even when it doesn't return anything, which I reckon now must be related to the PDO::FETCH routine.

Comment: You can check the row count using PDO as well with this method: $filtered_statement->rowCount(); Whether or not it is ok not to find anything is not a technical question; that depends on the business context in your case I guess.